# Grep lines between start & end pattern even end pattern in next file

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

My data is like:

- *First_file.txt*

  ```
  Start
  abcd
  efgh
  hijk
  lmn
  ```
- *Second_File.txt*

  ```
  opq
  rst
  uvw
  xyz
  END
  ```

---

I want to `grep` all the line between patterns *START* & *END*
even *END* pattern in next file

Output should be like:

```
abcd
efgh
hijk
lmn
opq
rst
uvw
xyz
```

---

Comment: what if there's `Start` string in `Second_File.txt` ?

Comment: you need to add what you tried to solve.. anyway, you'll find an answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns/ - wasn't able to find similar here).. as far as I know,  matching across files is default behavior with sed/awk

Comment: no start string come again until end string found, its our application logs.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: i try this command but its work for one file

:awk '/Pattern1/,/pattern2/' filename

Comment: are the `start` pattern is in `first file` **only** and `end` pattern in `second file` **only** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$ cat file1 file2 | awk '/pattern1/,/pattern2/'
```

Comment: _Useless use of cat._

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` Version:

```
sed -n '/start pattern/,/end pattern/p' file1 file2
```

> For Saving Output To New File

```
sed -n '/start pattern/,/end pattern/p' file1 file2 > output
```

Which will create for you new file called **output** include the desired result.